# Dollar sign in PatternReplaceFilterFactory

Tags: regex, search, solr, sunspot

In Solr I want "a$ap" to find "asap" as well as "a$ap". To achieve this I added this to my index and query analyzers in schema.xml and reindexed:

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="$" replacement="s"/>
```

But, "a$ap" only returns "a$ap" and "asap" only returns "asap". It's probably some silly syntax thing, but I don't know what is wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed it with a MappingCharFilterFactory.

I added this to the indexing and query analyzers:

```
<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping.txt"/>
```

Where mapping.txt looked like this:

```
"$" => "s"
```

That did the trick after reindexing!

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the $ as it is a special character for regex which means the end.

Use :-

```
    <fieldType name="test" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="\$" replacement="s" replace="all" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

The above field replaces it perfectly.